# Controller level parameter with ASP.NET MVC attribute routing

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Is there any way to add a parameter to the Controller Routing attribute?

something like:

```
[Route("controller/{id}/"]

public class Controller {
   public Controller(string id) { /*..*/ }

   [HttpGet]
   public ActionResult Get() { /*..*/ }
}
```

Comment: The route parameter is passed into each action method, not the controller's constructor.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Trying to add a common parameter to all routes on an existing controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `[FromRoute]` attribute on your controller method arguments should get you what you need.

**Example**

```
[Route("api/Test/{testId}")]
public class TestController: ControllerBase 
{
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("echo")]
    public void TestMethod([FromRoute]string testId)
    {
        return testId;
    }

}
```

Also see [this S.O.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58208688/validating-and-passing-controller-level-parameters-with-asp-net-mvc-attribute-ro) for more information.