# How to handle request with parameter of wrong type in .NET Core?

Tags: c#, api

So I have this problem that I have endpoint like

```cs
        [HttpGet("get/{id}")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Get([FromRoute] long? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
                return BadRequest();
            var result = await Mediator.Send(new GetIssueByIdQuery(id));
            return CreateResponse(result);
        }
```

and if I send request like

> ..../get/1

everything works fine. But if I give *id* parameter of different type, eg.:

> .../get/asd

the server automagically responds with some generic validation error and 404. Since the request doesn't even hit the endpoint, how can I handle this situation myself and return some more descriptive information to the client?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Validating and passing controller-level parameters with ASP.NET MVC attribute routing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58208688/validating-and-passing-controller-level-parameters-with-asp-net-mvc-attribute-ro)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could change type of `id` parameter to the string and try to parse it by yourself:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Get([FromRoute] string id)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(id))
        return BadRequest($"{nameof(id)} parameter should not be empty");
    if (!long.TryParse(id, out var longValue))
        return BadRequest($"{nameof(id)} should be convertible to long");

    var result = await Mediator.Send(new GetIssueByIdQuery(longValue));
    return CreateResponse(result);
}
```